# Multiple table inner join in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a link table linking IDs to 4 different tables:

**table 1**

```
Id  name
----------
1   eduard
2   remus
3   gabi
```

**table 2**

```
Id  ocupation
-----------------
1   manager
2   office worker
```

**table 3**

```
Id  sex
----------
1   male
2   female
```

**table 4**

```
Id  machine
------------
1   audi
2   mercedes
3   renault
```

**assoc_table**

```
Id   Id_table1  Id_table2 Id_table3  Id_table4
----------------------------------------------
1    1          1         1           1
2    2          1         1           3
3    3          2         1           3
```

I want to link these 4 tables together so I can look for example:

All colleagues driving the Mercedes car ....

Comment: Look up `JOIN`s.

Comment: It's not clear what are you expect. Please, provide some example of expected output ?

Comment: how can I merge all 4 tables based on ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.name, t2.ocupation, t3.sex, t4.machine
FROM
    assoc_table ast
        INNER JOIN
    table1 t1 ON t1.Id = ast.Id_table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t2.Id = ast.Id_table2
        INNER JOIN
    table3 t3 ON t3.Id = ast.Id_table3
        INNER JOIN
    table4 t4 ON t4.Id = ast.Id_table4
WHERE
    t4.Id = 2
```

Comment: or if you don't know the id you can write where t4.machine = 'mercedes'